# Lost connection to the server after changing gateway

Tags: debian, proxmox

In a Proxmox server (Debian), I changed the gateway from vmbr0 to enp0s31f6, as this:

```
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
    address  192.168.1.11
    netmask  255.255.255.0
-   address  192.168.1.1
+   gateway  192.168.1.1

 auto vmbr0
 iface vmbr0 inet static
    address  192.168.1.10
    netmask  255.255.255.0
-   gateway  192.168.1.11
    bridge-ports enp0s31f6
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
```

After rebooting I can't ping 192.168.1.10 nor 192.168.1.11, can someone explain me why I cannot connect anymore?. In a bridged network the gw should by defined in `vmbr0`?.

The ip address of `enp0s31f6` initially was wrong (it pointed to 192.168.1.1, which is the router that acts as a gateway), that's why I changed it from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `enp0s31f6` interface is a port of the `vmbr0` bridge, you cannot assign any ip addresses to it. Also, if you want assign the ip address to the `enp0s31f6` interface, you should change the `vmbr0` address, otherwise you will have the same subnet on two interfaces.

```
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address  192.168.2.10
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    bridge-ports none
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
```

But more correct configuration for a bridging networking is assignment of the ip address to the `vmbr0` interface. In such case your interfaces file should look something like:

```
iface enp0s31f6 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    bridge-ports enp0s31f6
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
```

Comment: Thanks Anton Danilov, the conclusion is when an interface is bridged _never touch it!_, use the bridge.